# Valdiation data which send by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I make form by React. After submitted form, I need to validate data from Laravel. Problem is that sending data is diffrent than normal form. So any values from dorm is in array data.

```
//normal form
$request->title
//sending from React
$request->data['title']
```

So, look at this code

```
class articleRequest extends Request
{
    public function rulse(){
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            //other rules
        ];
    }
}
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function atoreArticle(articleRequest $request){
        Textads::create([
            'title'=> $request->data['title'],
            //other
        ]);
    }
}
```

But I have an error that title field is required. Without valdiation everything is ok. How I can solve my problem?

Comment: Make sure that you have `name` attribute set on the text field. Secondly, I would suggest to use `$request->input('title')` to get the title. I would also suggest to `return $request->all()` to your rect app and then console log to see what you are getting

Comment: React app and form is ok becouse if I resignation with validation, it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
$rules = [
        'title' => 'required',
        //other rules
    ];

Validator::make($request->all(), $rules)->validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

will this work?   or $request->all()->data ?

```
  $validator = Validator::make($request->data, [
            title'' => 'required'
        ],[
           //custom error message if needed
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'data' => $validator->messages(),
                'message' => "error"
            ], 422);
        }
```

Comment: `$request->data` should give you null... There is no property or method as `$request->data`. Use `$request->all()`

Comment: yeah I agree, $request->all();  I think I only put data because he said something about using react and I have never used it so didn't question it.